# what does this return statement do?

Tags: c++, function, return

below is a dummy function. i saw something like this somewhere. i didnt understand the return part.

```
int SomeFunction(int SomeVar)
{
    //do the calculations
    ...
   return SomeVar != 0
}
```

how does the last line work? what does it return?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Closed as "not constructive". Really? Wut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function returns 1 if `SomeVar` is nonzero and 0 if `SomeVar` is zero.

The result of expression `SomeVar != 0` is of `bool` type (`false` or `true`). A `bool` type is implicitly converted to `int` (0 or 1 respectively).

Answer (score 1):

It returns an integer representation of boolean. 0 if the statement evaluates to false, 1- otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This will return 1 when SomeVar  is not zero and vice versa.